# How to create nested tree view for departments Odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I'd like to have visualization for my departments in odoo v 10.0, like so:

```
Parent Department 1

    -> Child department 1
          --> Job position of this department

          --> Job position of this department
     -> Child department 2

          --> Job position of this department

          --> Job position of this department
Parent department 2
```

instead of simply having Parent department / Child department

How this might be achieved? Should I use grouping or iteration or something else in view? If possible - with example please

Comment: add group by filter in search view and add it as default

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<record id="action_hr_department_test" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Departments</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.department</field>
    <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
   <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <field name="context">{'group_by':['parent_id','name','manager_id']}</field>
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_hr_department_test" name="Departments Test"
         action="action_hr_department_test"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, this works for the department, but what about job positions in those departments?

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't show job positions related to department and I have same department as child and as single entry, like this:
1. Parent -> Child  2. Child 
So it duplicates